# Are Azure Managed Identities enough?

Tags: azure, security, azure-managed-identity, azure-mysql-database

I keep reading about how Azure Managed Identities are the way to go to secure access to Azure resources, and i totally get the convenience and level of security they offer. But i often worry that at the same time they leave open the possibility that any vulnerability to *any* application that is running within my resource can then leverage that identity to do things that i may not want it to do, not just the application i want to give access to that resource.

This method of securing things while convenient has always felt awkward. Its like if i need to give a friend of mine access to my apartment to watch my dog while im on vacation, instead of giving my friend my keys i instead just slip the keys through the mail slot and they have 4 other roommates. (lets pretend that these keys are soul-bound to everyone that lives there and cannot be stolen)

Is it possible to combine both Managed Identities with traditional credentials to consume resources?

A specific example might be, i have a JAVA spring based application that consumes Azure Database for MySQL that i have deployed into a Kubernetes environment. I am using a sidecar container with NGINX to provide external HTTP access to that application. Using a pod-managed identity here implies to me that both the JAVA application and NGINX will have access to the database, when i *only* want my application to be the one that has access. Certainly there are other architectural approaches that i could take in this example but more trying to outline my concerns with managed identities alone.

Comment: it is enough to authorize your web app with no user interaction.

Comment: Sure but security > convenience

Comment: Using pod-identity, you can define multiple identities and then choose which app is allowed to use the related identity.